# Error while running shell script to connect to Oracle as root user

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, ubuntu-14.04

I have a shell script file(Oracle_UserData.sh) on my ubuntu VM (shows below),

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "login to oracle 11g as sys"
chmod -R 755 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus -S sys/password as sysdba <<EOF
        create user $USER identified by $PASSWORD;
        grant all privileges to $USER;
        exit;
EOF
```

and I have another script file that runs as root, which would trigger the previous script file to run. (It runs as root because I'm passing the script as part of the Amazon EC2 user data).

```
#!/bin/bash
export USER=root
export PASSWORD=password

cd "/home/ubuntu/"
sh Oracle_UserData.sh
output: {all: '| tee -a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log'}
```

I am trying to create a new db user by running the these scripts, but it failed.  I'm not sure if it's because the root user cannot access the environment variable or some other issue? I got the error

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
```

I tried to make those environment variable as a local variable by exporting them (ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_SID), and I got the error that

```
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

(If I just make this script as a local file, and run it locally as Ubuntu, it works fine. User can be created with no issue.)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you debugged the script by adding things like `set -x` and `env` to the top of the script?  Can you record the environment in a log file you can scrutinize?  Without that sort of information, and knowledge of what the correct values should be, you're probably hosed.  It seems odd to be passing the user name and password as environment variables too.

Comment: $username and $password is not part of the env variables, those are being passed as a input script.

Comment: If you say so (though I'm afraid I am not convinced you know what you're saying).  But then we know that the script you're showing is not the one you're running...or there are some very peculiar properties to one of the programs that you're using that are not obvious to an everyday shell programmer.  In the absence of any other information, your shell is going to put nothing (an empty string, no quotes or anything) in place of `$USER` and `$PASSWORD` in the script -- and the command that is executed will not see `$USER` and `$PASSWORD` at all.

Comment: hey, I'm sorry about the confusion. I just added some more info to my post, do you mind to take a look again? thanks a bunch!

Comment: I just debugged the script, so if I call "env", it shows different env variables than the ubuntu user. There's no ORACLE related variable, what should I do now? I cannot change the way that AWS runs the script as root though, sigh!

Comment: You probably need to replace `sh Oracle_UserData.sh` with `. Oracle_UserData.sh` (or `source Oracle_UserData.sh`).  As it stands, you run the Oracle user data script in a sub-shell, so any changes it makes to the environment only affect the sub-shell.  If you use `.` (or `source` -- dot is the classic name to use, and is POSIX compliant, but Bash imported the name `source` from C shell as an alias for `.`), the script is run as part of the current shell.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But this didn't seem to work, I got the same error,Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Comment: I give in.  We're working blind with no information about what the trace of the output looks like.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: still really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem solved by following the link below,
http://www.dadbm.com/how-to-fix-ora-12547-tns-lost-contact-when-try-to-connect-to-oracle/

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin

ls -ltr oracle
-rwxr-xr-x    1 oracle   oinstall       136803483 Mar 16 20:32 oracle

chmod 6751 oracle

ls -ltr oracle
-rwsr-s--x    1 oracle   oinstall       136803483 Mar 16 20:32 oracle
```